# Back Word Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

There's a puzzle given to my friend by his professor. Answer is one real word only.

Puzzle: ifhgormt

Clue: "Sometimes you have to go forward by going backwards"

zyx..

Comment: Oh wait. There's no A. Sorry. It's ifhgormt

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: Per [a question you deleted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125758/find-the-riddle-word-not-so-easy) (after the framing was pointed out as suspect), I'm suspicious that this is actually from some sort of competition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It think the word is

> **RUSTLING**

> Feeding the letters ifhgormt into an [ATBASH cipher](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-atbash-cipher/amp/) decoder after following the ‘backwards’ hint I got **Rustling**.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: idk, but I just upvoted it. Pretty straightforward answer